# Event delegation in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Im adding few radio buttons within a container dynamically using Jquery append method and added the event handler for all the radio buttons but its not working

Question:

Whenever I click the radio button within the container, I need a set of commands to be executed..

fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/Z86kW/1/

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').append('<input type="radio" name="radio1"/>');
    $('#container').append('<input type="radio" name="radio2"/>');
    $('#container').append('<input type="radio" name="radio3"/>');


    $( "#container" ).on( "click", "radio", function( event ) {

            alert( $( this ).text() );
            })
})
```

css

```
#container{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

html

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: You should probably be using checkboxes if you intend to use it like checkboxes with no radio groups (same name).

Comment: Here's how I'd do it -> http://jsfiddle.net/Z86kW/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, You missed `:` with selector

```
$( "#container" ).on( "click", ":radio", function( event ) {
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/Z86kW/4/)

`$(":radio")` is equivalent to `$("[type=radio]")`.

Comment: Thanks it worked...Should I use ":" for radio button only or for all objects?

Comment: @user1050619, `$(":radio")` is equivalent to `$("[type=radio]")`. You need to provide correct selector. What all object you are referring to?

Comment: @Satpal..Thanks..I was referring to this document - https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/...when he selects all "a" elements he doesn't uses it..what is the difference..

Comment: @user1050619, `a` is a html tag. You can use `p`, `div` tags. Here `radio` is not a tag, Here I have used equivalent of attribute value selector `[type=radio]`

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to select all elements of type radio then you must use [`:radio`](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) selector.

```
$("#container" ).on( "click", ":radio", function( event ) {
     alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z86kW/5/)

or you can also use `input[type=radio]`.

```
$("#container" ).on( "click", "input[type=radio]", function( event ) {
     alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z86kW/8/)

Answer (score 0):

I have tweak the jquery code. refer this `url`  http://jsfiddle.net/Z86kW/9/

PS: Also, keep the name value same to have only one radio selected at a time.

Cheers,
Ashok